# My open windows all suddenly minimized. How do I get them back?

Tags: windows

Sometimes when dragging a window around on the Windows 7 desktop, all of my other open windows will suddenly minimize. I can go to the task bar and reopen them, one by one, but is there a way to get them all back at once? And is there a way to turn off this annoying behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be [Aero Shake](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/minimize-windows-on-the-desktop-using-shake).

You can shake the window that you were moving and your windows will be restored.

You can also disable Aero Shake, following instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/12156/how-do-i-disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7):

- Go to Run (Windows+R) and type gpedit.msc
- Navigate to User configuration > Administratives Templates > Desktop
- Search for "Turn off Aero Shake window minimizing mouse gesture" and enable the policy.

Comment: "Windows cannot find 'gpedit.msc'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Comment: Some Windows 7 editions don't have gpedit enabled. Check [this post](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions) for instructions on how to enable it.

Comment: so, run a `setup.exe` from untrusted source?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's either that or upgrading your Windows 7 edition, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you shake a window (left-right rapidly or another direction) then it minimizes all windows except that one. To get them back, shake the first window again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Maximize and close it with Shift pressed.
3. Windows Explorer should open maximized.